# Change Magento Layout on FAQ Page

Tags: magento, layout

Can anyone assist me in changing the layout to 1column.phtml on the magento faq page? (mymagentosite.com/faq).

I have changed many lines in catalog.xml without luck.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If the faq page was created as a Magento CMS page you can change the layout of that one page by logging into admin then to CMS > Pages, click on the FAQ page, then under the Design section (left nav) you can change the layout template.

If you installed an FAQ type extension you will need to find the xml file of the extension itself in one of your themes.

Comment: Hi. The FAQ in question is the default install with Magento. It's front end is located at /faq. Thanks!